# How to output a list of numbers in an Arraylist without outputting the Brackets and Commas?

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

I have the following code used to help me find the prime numbers between 1 and whatever the user inputs. The only problem is, I have to output the numbers without the Brackets and Commas. How do I do that?

```
    System.out.println("\nLab1la\n");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the primes upperbond ==>> ");
    final int MAX = input.nextInt();
    boolean primes[];
    primes = new boolean[MAX];

    ArrayList<Integer>PrimeFactor = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 2; i < MAX + 1 ; i++)
    {
        PrimeFactor.add(i); 
    }


    CompositeNumbers(PrimeFactor);
    System.out.println("COMPUTING RIME NUMBERS");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("PRIMES BETWEEN 1 AND " + MAX);
    System.out.print(PrimeFactor);

}

public static void CompositeNumbers(ArrayList<Integer> PrimeFactor)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PrimeFactor.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!isPrime(PrimeFactor.get(i)))
        { 
            PrimeFactor.remove(i);
            i--;

        }
    }
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < n +1/2; i++)
    {
        if (n%i == 0)
        {
            return false;

        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

}

Comment: Maybe use a for loop instead of just passing in the entire `ArrayList` to `System.out`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, can you liberate a little more?

Answer (score 1):

Just output each value in turn. For example:

```
// TODO: Rename PrimeFactor to primeFactors to follow Java naming conventions
for (int value : PrimeFactor)
{
    System.out.print(value);
    System.out.print(" "); // Or whatever separator you want
}
```

(This will output an extra space at the end; getting rid of that is *slightly* fiddly, but not too hard...)

Or use something like Guava's [`Joiner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) class:

```
System.out.println(Joiner.on(' ').join(PrimeFactor));
```

Comment: The following works, but how can I add that to so It can output the "Prime Numbers" which is the CompositeNumbers(PrimeFactor). All that outputs is the numbers 2 to n.

Comment: @Bob: I don't understand what you mean. Your question was how to output the contents of a list without brackets and commas that come in the default implementation. If the list doesn't contain the numbers you want, that's an entirely different question.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I put 'CompositeNumbers(PrimeFactor);' right before 'system.out.println(PrimeFactor)' because it gave me the prime numbers. I put your code, and I seemed to only get what the ArrayList PrimeFactor would give me. How would I tweek the code so I can get the CompositeNumbers value to output without commas and brackets.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Bob: Well you'd still call `CompositeNumbers`. I wasn't suggesting replacing *all* of your code - just the bit that was printing out `PrimeNumbers` - your current `System.out.print(PrimeFactor);` line.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `System.out.print(" ");`. I am sure it will help.